# Does Felyne Temper affect arrows as did in classic games?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In classic games, Felyne Temper is known to [increase damage of not only bowgun bullets but also bow arrows](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/44hvvy/do_felyne_temper_and_sharpshooter_affect_bows/), while Felyne Sharpshooter didn't affect normal shots. (For those who are wondering, Felyne Temper is a random meal skill which boosts bowgun damage in some amount, and Felyne Sharpshooter is a fixed meal skill which affects Normal Ammo of a bowgun.)

However, in this series, [Felyne Sharpshooter's text has changed that it also affects normal shots of a bow](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Felyne+Sharpshooter). My question is then, does Felyne Temper affect bow's arrows as it did in series up to Generations Ultimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description for Felyne Temper reads as follows:

> Increases bowgun damage, but also increases deviation.

Sure enough, I just tested and bow damage was not affected.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't used with believing in what the text says because there were too many things hidden in old skill text. Thanks.